# .Net to COM Interop Tester

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop, tlbimp

I made a class in C# that I am exposing to COM. I can register it just fine using RegAsm.exe.

I would like to test it before I send it off, but using TlbImp.exe gives me an error of "Type libaray was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assemply."

What is a good way to test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a VB macros in word\excel\etc:

```
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("progid here")
Call obj.SomeMethodForTest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PowerShell](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_com.htm):

```
$myObj = new-object -comObject ProgId
```

Comment: My COM object is called loggingAPI, how would I use powershell to load that?

Comment: It's the same as with VB - `$myObj = new-object -comObject loggingAPI`